# Get ID from parent div that has display:none in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, parent

I'd like to obtain the id of the parent of a particular element. The parent element is hidden using display:none, as I need it to not obtain space.

I've written a Javascript that obtains the id from an element's parent, based on the parents class.

```
function getParentDivId(divName, classNameParent) {
    do {
        divName = divName.parentNode; // get parentdiv from initial div
        if (divName.className == classNameParent) { // check if parent div belongs to specified class
            return divName.id; // return the id of the parent div
        }
    } while (divName.parentNode) { // while div has parent do above function
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <!-- code for a single main category with several subcategories -->
    <!-- all subcategories can be hidden by setting the subcategories display property to none-->
    <!-- all subcategories can be shown by setting the categories display property to inline-block-->
    <div class="categories" id="calgemeen">
        <div class="item" id="algemeen">algemeen
            <div class="press" onclick="goSubcategory(this, contact);"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcategories" id="scalgemeen">
        <!--subcategories can be shown using item, note the weird -->
        <!--syntax ><div this is necessary to remove the whitespace between inline-blocks-->
        <div class="subcategory" id="info"><div class="item">info</div></div
        ><div class="subcategory" id="contact"><div class="item">contact
            <div class="press" onclick="goSubcategory(this, spaans);"></div></div></div
        ><div class="subcategory" id="route"><div class="item">route</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="categories" id="chuisartsen">
        <div class="item">huisartsen
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcategories" id="schuisartsen">
        <div class="subcategory" id="spaans"><div class="item">spaans</div></div
                ><div class="subcategory" id="engels"><div class="item">stelten</div></div
            ><div class="subcategory" id="frans"><div class="item">willemsen</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Information concerning ID's returned:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goSubcategory(current, subcategory) {
        var sc_current = getParentDivId(current, "subcategories");
        var sc_target = getParentDivId(subcategory, "subcategories");
        console.log("current: " + sc_current);
        console.log("target: " + sc_target);
    }
</script>
```

This returns in the console when onclick="goSubcategory(this, contact)

```
current: null
target: scalgemeen
```

This is correct, as 'this' does not have a parent in the subcategories class and
'contact' does have a parent in the subcategories class,id='scalgemeen'

However, onclick="goSubcategory(this, spaans) returns in the console

```
current: scalgemeen
target: scalgemeen
```

This is incorrect, as 'spaans' should have a parent with id='schuisartsen'

Note that while onclick="goSubcategory(this, spaans) is selected all elements with class categories are display:none as well as element row2.

Is a method available that allows me to obtain the correct target id.

Comment: <div class="press" onclick="goSubcategory(this, contact);"> what is contact here, seems like it should be in quotes

Comment: @shadow: contact refers to the element id.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem. A do...while loop should be like:

```
do {
//do something
}
while(conditon==true);
```

So do the below. It might work for you, if you don't have any errors elsewhere.

```
function getParentDivId(divName, classNameParent) {
    do {
        divName = divName.parentNode; // get parentdiv from initial div
        if (divName.className == classNameParent) { // check if parent div belongs to specified class
            return divName.id; // return the id of the parent div
        }
    } while (divName.parentNode); // while div has parent do above function
}
```

If you want to break the loop, then use the keyword `break;`.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for taking the time to check out my problem. However divName.parentNode is in itself a condition, as long as it is not NULL the loop will continue, and hold (and return null) as soon as it becomes NULL.

Comment: yeah. You need to do that

Comment: The while loop ends as soon as the first instance of subcategories is found, this does not seem to be the problem. I'm pretty sure the issue is related to the fact that the subcategories element that spaans belongs to has display: none property.

Comment: if so, you should accept my answer so that it might be useful to someone @jhws

Comment: the problem does not seem related to this function.